# "Cannot Implicitly convert type 'float' to 'int'" even when I'm not using any ints

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

Here's my code:

```
float SmoothNoise(float x, float y)
{
    float fractX = x - (int)x;
    float fractY = y - (int)y;

    float x1 = ((int)x + noiseWidth) % noiseWidth;
    float y1 = ((int)y + noiseHeight) % noiseHeight;

    float x2 = ((int)x + noiseWidth - 1f) % noiseWidth;
    float y2 = ((int)y + noiseHeight - 1f) % noiseHeight;

    float value = 0f;

    value += fractX * fractY * noise[x1, y1];
    value += fractX * (1f - fractY) * noise[x1, y2];
    value += (1f - fractX) * fractY * noise[x2, y1];
    value += (1f - fractX) * (1f - fractY) * noise[x2, y2];

    return value;
}
```

The errors occur on these four lines:

```
value += fractX * fractY * noise[x1, y1];
value += fractX * (1f - fractY) * noise[x1, y2];
value += (1f - fractX) * fractY * noise[x2, y1];
value += (1f - fractX) * (1f - fractY) * noise[x2, y2];
```

As you can see, the only ints I use are explicitly casted, so I'm just really confused as to where it thinks I'm trying to implicitly convert anything to an int.

I should mention there are 8 identical errors of this kind, 2 for each of the four lines. It boggles my mind.

noise is an array of type float[,]

Comment: `noise[x1, y1]`? indexer likely wants `int` parameter

Comment: Not using any ints? I see tons of them around.

Comment: Heh, yeah, I meant I'm not using any ints that aren't explicitly converted from a float, but I couldn't fit all that in the title.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're trying to use float values as array indexer in the code fragments like: `noise[x1, y1]`.

Array indexers can be only integers in .NET, but you've declared them as `float x1, y1`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm sorry for the dumb question, it's just one of those small things that slips under your radar.

Comment: @user1920556 you're welcome. almost everyone makes silly mistakes from time to time, there is no problem. ;)